# convert XGBRegressor( booster='gblinear', objective='reg:squarederror') to ONNX returns error

Tags: python, xgboost, onnx, onnxruntime

i was working on a simple 3d regressor model and i used the following parameters

**#my code extract:**

```
from mlprodict.onnxrt import OnnxInference
import numpy
import onnxruntime as onnx_RT
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris, load_diabetes, make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, XGBRegressor, DMatrix, train as train_xgb
from skl2onnx.common.data_types import FloatTensorType
from skl2onnx import convert_sklearn, to_onnx, update_registered_converter
from skl2onnx.common.shape_calculator import (
    calculate_linear_classifier_output_shapes,
    calculate_linear_regressor_output_shapes)
from onnxmltools.convert.xgboost.operator_converters.XGBoost import (
    convert_xgboost)
from onnxmltools.convert import convert_xgboost as convert_xgboost_booster

data = load_iris()
X = data.data[:, :2]
y = data.target

ind = numpy.arange(X.shape[0])
numpy.random.shuffle(ind)
X = X[ind, :].copy()
y = y[ind].copy()

models_01 = XGBRegressor(  booster='gblinear', objective='reg:squarederror')
models_01.fit(X, y)

**#Register the converter for XGBRegressor**
    update_registered_converter(
        XGBRegressor, 'XGBoostXGBRegressor',
        calculate_linear_regressor_output_shapes, convert_xgboost,
        options={'nocl': [True, True], 'zipmap': [False, False, 'columns']}
        )

**#convert to ONNX**
  onnx_result = convert_sklearn( models_01, "My_simple_XGBRegressor",
      [('input', FloatTensorType([None, X.shape[1]  ]))],
      target_opset={'': 12, 'ai.onnx.ml': 2}, options={'zipmap': False},
      )
```

I then tried to convert to load an inference session but it always returned the following error.....

**#test the ONNX model**
`onnx_model_inference = onnx_RT.InferenceSession(  onnx_result.SerializeToString()  )    #throws an error`

**#the error**
**InvalidGraph: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 10 : INVALID_GRAPH : Load model from models_01.onnx failed: This is an invalid model. In Node, ("TreeEnsembleRegressor", TreeEnsembleRegressor, "ai.onnx.ml", -1) : ("input": tensor(float),) -> ("variable": tensor(float),) , Error Attribute 'nodes_falsenodeids' is expected to have field 'ints'**
**#the error**

please help... Thank you.

expected results is an error free result of the onnx model.

**#test the ONNX model**
`onnx_model_inference = onnx_RT.InferenceSession(  onnx_result.SerializeToString()  )    #throws NO ERROR`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I also have an XGBRegressor model but I loaded a checkpoint that I saved before, and this solved the problem for me.

```
from onnxmltools import convert
from skl2onnx.common.data_types import FloatTensorType

# Convert source model to onnx
initial_type = [('float_input', FloatTensorType([None, source_model.n_features_in_]))]
    
onnx = convert.convert_xgboost(model, initial_types=initial_type, target_opset=12)
```

Extra:
I have used a *custom_objective* and a *custom_metric* while training so if that's your case you can use ...

```
model.objective = None
model.eval_metric = None
```

... before converting the model.